# Arguments for/against hosting a whole site on a CDN?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, scalability, cdn

I am working at a newer startup, and the VP of engineering is really taken with the idea that our web site could be made to be hosted on a CDN and just access services via AJAX calls to populate the data. The advantage, he claims, is the client facing static sites cost next to nothing to host.

However, it seems it will just make programming the site much more difficult and actually may decrease performance as what would take one HTTP request for a site could take a dozen of AJAX calls. Frankly, I can't think of any real advantage of going for a pure JS/HTML solution versus an ASP .Net MVC site that uses unobtrusive JS with HTML and AJAX where it makes sense (updating parts of a page versus loading the whole thing).

The hard part is that I may have to make this argument to the CEO, so if I can qualify in terms of performance and development costs, that'd be great.

Comment: You could make the argument to the CEO in terms of how many customers you will lose. As a percentage, the number of users with JavaScript disabled is low, but even 1% of, say, Australia's population is 200,000 people for whom the site wouldn't work - and 1% of the US is what, 3,000,000 people? I agree that the VP's vision would make developing and maintaining the site more difficult too.

Comment: If you feel the development track is that far away from the kind of development you want to do, I would recommend forgoing the argument and look for a new job. You aren't talking about trivial stylistic differences but major architectural and ideological changes.

Comment: And this should probably be on programmers.stackexhange.com not here

Answer (score 0):

Get out of your comfort zone for a while and quit belly aching. Your VP is probably talking about CloudFlare or something similar. Take a chance and learn something new.

The short answer is yes, if the app your company is working on fits within the model that supports a client-side view model, the benefits can be quite fantastic.